# Only show posts from selected post categories

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, buddypress

I’m building a news aggregator site where I fetch news from a couple of different news sources that converts into Posts. I want my registered users to have the possibility to choose which news sources (Post Categories) they want to see in their feed on my website (not BuddyPress own Activity Feed, but the feed where I list all mixed news posts from different sources).

Is this possible with a custom field or something? So that when the user edits their profile, they can tick the box next to the source they want to add/delete form their feed.

An example of what I want each user to be able to have the freedom to do:

> “Select which news sources (Post Categories) you want to read from:”
>
> [ ] USA Today
>
> [ ] The Guardian
>
> [✓] The New Yorker

The specific user above should now only see news from The New Yorker in the news feed.

How would you guys accomplish a solution like this with BuddyPress?

### Update

Clarification:

Emma logs onto her account (via BuddyPress plugin) and goes to her Account Settings. In the Account Settings page, I want to list a couple of Checkboxes with news sources. If Emma selects two of the Checkboxes (i.e. The Guardian & USA Today), then Emma wants the WP_Query to only select posts from these Post Categories (which is the different newspapers).

**1.** How should I create these fields using Advanced Custom Fields and present them on the Profile Settings page?

**2.** How should I take the values selected from the Advanced Custom Fields in Profile Settings, and filter the WP_Query (which fetches all posts) by Post Category?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

You can use the Taxonomy field type, and use this to get the selected values.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/#working-with array values

```
$values = get_field('field_name');
if($values)
{
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach($values as $value)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Then just use a custom query and filter by the category IDs.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

`$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38' );`

Comment: Thank you, Josh. I've created a field called "Sources" (news sources) with a taxonomy rule (http://i.imgur.com/M360K38.png) which referes to one of my news sources (called "Fightermag"). Am I on the right track? Should I just keep on adding fields for each news source I have?

Comment: So create a custom field, called something like "Sources", and use the "Taxonomy" field type. The other settings should be pretty self explanatory. For the Rule make it a "User" rule that is "equal to" "All". So it will look something like this. http://i.imgur.com/7KliYz9.png. And your "Edit User" page should look like this. http://i.imgur.com/5Gox33z.png. Then to get the values you would use the code that I mentioned, with `get_field('field_name')` looking something like `get_field('sources', $userIDHere)` and you should get back an array of category IDs to query with.

Comment: I'm with you all the way, everything is setup according to your instructions, and it looks just like your images. Now when I try echo the category IDs in the "Edit User" page it yields nothing. I've tried to print out the user ID - that works. This code doesn't do anything for me: `echo get_field('sources', get_current_user_id());` - Why doesn't it return the array?

Comment: Josh, could it be that the user of that user_id hasn't chosen any news sources yet?

Comment: I may have led you astray.. Not sure. The example I gave you will show the "Sources" selection on the Edit Profile page inside the WordPress dashboard, but not on the front end "Settings" page that BuddyPress sets up. Not sure if this is a problem or not. Second, it probably wouldn't return anything if there were no sources selected.. So you would have to test by selecting some. Also note that it may not show up if you try to echo it in the WordPress dashboard area. I'm not sure if the plugin functions work the same (or at all) unless they are used on the front end.

Comment: Okay I understand. This sentence describes what I want to the fullest, I think: "Let users select from a checklist of available post categories and save as their choice as a custom field (preferably in a custom user profile page (In my case BuddyPress) rather than the WP Dashboard). So, the checkboxes in the Wordpress User Settings should be in the BuddyPress Edit Profile page. Do you think we're far from a solution? This guys want the exact same thing: http://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/34tzvu/user_profiles_custom_fields_let_users_select_from/

Answer (score 0):

I have made this work, take the input on selection of categories and save the ids of selected categories in custom table and query saved ids ..